# JSON object name twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express

Im just fresh with node.js and i don't get this completely. Can someone explain me what im doing wrong?

This is how i make a new Product

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
const product = new Products({
    title: req.body.title,
    url: req.body.imgUrl
});
```

When i log the received data from body its look ok

```
{ title: 'Someting', url: 'http' }
```

This is the class

```
module.exports = class Product {
constructor(title, url) {

    this.title = title,
        this.url = url
    console.log(this);

}
save() {
    const p = path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
        'data',
        'products.json'
    );

    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        let products = [];
        // if (!err) {
        //     products.push = JSON.parse(fileContent);
        // }
        products.push(this);
        fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
            console.log(err);

        });
    })
}
```

and this how my prd.json looks like.

```
[{"title":{"title":"Something","url":"http"}}]
```

Why i get the (title) object name twice??

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object to the constructor. So you are doing `this.title={title:'...',url:'...'}`

```
const product = new Product({
    title: req.body.title,
    url: req.body.imgUrl
});
```

You should pass two arguments:

```
const product = new Product( req.body.title , req.body.imgUrl );
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have find the problem too. But how should  i can know which var come in the correct in the class. Should i stick to the order??

Comment: Yes. The order is important. In this case you expect two arguments, but you passed one. So, that single object will pass as the first argument.